# Trouble with restoring pretrained model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I ran the demo program of word2vec which is included in TensorFlow, and now trying to restore the pretrained model from files, but it doesn't work.

I ran this script file:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py

Then I tried to run this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tensorflow as tf

FILENAME_META = "model.ckpt-70707299.meta"
FILENAME_CHECKPOINT = "model.ckpt-70707299"


def main():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FILENAME_META)
        saver.restore(sess, FILENAME_CHECKPOINT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It fails with the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word2vec_restore.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "word2vec_restore.py", line 11, in main
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FILENAME_META)
  File "/home/kato/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1431, in import_meta_graph
    return _import_meta_graph_def(read_meta_graph_file(meta_graph_or_file))
  File "/home/kato/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1321, in _import_meta_graph_def
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/kato/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 247, in import_graph_def
    op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'Skipgram'
```

I regard I have understood the API document of TensorFlow, and I implemented the code above as is written in it. Am I using the Saver object in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by myself. I wondered where the key 'Skipgram' comes from, and dug the source code. To solve the problem, just add the following on the top:

```
from tensorflow.models.embedding import gen_word2vec
```

I still don't understand exactly what I am doing, but maybe this is because it is necessary to load a related library written in C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if checkpoint and checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Where `checkpoint_dir`is path to folder that contains checkpoint files, not full path to meta or checkpoint files. Tensorflow picks the latest checkpoint itself from the specified folder.

Comment: It fails with "ValueError: No variables to save" at the first line.